# node.js image upload best approach

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, image-uploading, scalability

I have a web application that takes an image uploaded by the user, uploads it to S3 (via multer-s3) and gets the url, collects some metadata from it via a module called "sharp" (i.e. dimensions, mime type and whatnot), and then writes this info to db.

These are very high resolution photos (starting from 2 up to 19 mb) and I'm not sure what would be the best way of handling them. Should I write them into files when I first get them, and then stream from there, or should I just continue keeping it in memory until I'm done.

The part after upload, where I run the image through sharp, is the part that worries me the most. Because sharp can't work with streams, I convert the stream into a buffer as such:

```
async getImageDimensions(fileStream){
  let buffer = await this._streamToBuffer(fileStream);
  let metadata = await sharp(buffer).metadata();
  return {width: metadata.width, height: metadata.height};
}

_streamToBuffer(stream){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let buffers = [];
    stream.on('error', reject);
    stream.on('data', (data) => buffers.push(data));
    stream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(buffers)));
  });
}
```

The above snippet concurrently runs with two other async functions, and the findings are inserted into db. Am I doing it wrong? Would writing to a local file and pointing sharp to that file be better?

Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sharp` supports Stream-based input with Promise-based (i.e. async/await) output.

Here's a modified version of your example to demonstrate how this might be achieved.

```
async getImageDimensions(fileStream){
    const writableStream = sharp();
    fileStream.pipe(writableStream);
    const metadata = await writableStream.metadata();
    return {width: metadata.width, height: metadata.height};
}
```

In terms of approach, `metadata()` does not decode any of the pixel data, usually the bulk of any image file, so you could experiment with truncating `fileStream` as dimensions are near the start.

Comment: In the meantime, I figured the sharper use with streams out, but I forgot to update here. Thanks a lot.

As for the metadata() explanation, great news, thanks